# How can I get the result of a conditional filtering

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to filter a list like that:

```
function INFO_3D_004() {

var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("IMP_0_LISTE PROJETS");

var listePRO = PROsheet.getRange(1,1,PROsheet.getLastRow(),4).getValues();
 
let listePRO_2 = listePRO.filter(function (x) {
      for (i = 0; i < listePRO.length; i++) {

        if (listePRO[i][1] === false && listePRO[i][3] === true) {
        }
        Logger.log(listePRO[i][0])
      }
    })
  
  Logger.log(listePRO_2)
  let values_2 = listePRO_2.values();
  Logger.log(values_2)
}
```

The first logger `Logger.log(listePRO[i][0])` exactly give me the information I need, but the 2 next loggers `ogger.log(listePRO_2)` && `Logger.log(values_2)` return empty values...

I want to be able to filter creating a `let listePRO_2 =` because I would like to filter it 2 times (creating listPRO_3 and listePRO_4) and then compare it to another list

Here is how the spreadsheet looks like :

| listPRO | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ORSAY | true | red | true |
| REMBRANDT_AMSTERDAM | false | blue | false |
| OMAN | false | blue | true |
| ORSAY | true | red | true |

so here I would like to retrieve the values of all the OMAN raw in the "let listePRO_2 ="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, I think that the method for using `filter` is required to be modified. In this case, it is required to return `true` or `false`. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function INFO_3D_004() {
  var PROsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("IMP_0_LISTE PROJETS");
  var listePRO = PROsheet.getRange(1, 1, PROsheet.getLastRow(), 4).getValues();
  let listePRO_2 = listePRO.filter(x => x[1] === false && x[3] === true);
  Logger.log(listePRO_2)
}
```

- When your showing table is used, `listePRO_2` is `[["OMAN",false,"blue",true]]`.
- Although I'm not sure `2` of `listePRO_2`, if you want to retrieve the column "C", please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      let listePRO_2 = listePRO.filter(x => x[1] === false && x[3] === true);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      let listePRO_2 = listePRO.filter(x => x[1] === false && x[3] === true).map(r => r[2]); // or .map(r => [r[2]])
    ```

#### Testing:

```js
const listePRO = [["listPRO", 1, 2, 3], ["ORSAY", true, "red", true], ["REMBRANDT_AMSTERDAM", false, "blue", false], ["OMAN", false, "blue", true], ["ORSAY", true, "red", true]];
const res1 = listePRO.filter(x => x[1] === false && x[3] === true);
const res2 = listePRO.filter(x => x[1] === false && x[3] === true).map(r => r[2]);
console.log(res1)
console.log(res2)
```

#### Note:

- I'm worried whether I could correctly understand your expected value. If that was not your expected value, can you provide your expected value from your showing table? By this, I would like to modify the script.

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)